# How to distort text in InDesign CC 2018?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, text, effects

I created a file that's 205mm W x 290mm H, and one of the adverts on the page (179 mm W x 124 mm H) has a logo similar to this in terms of being bent:

[image: Everlast logo size]

except in Antique Olive Nord font and slightly wider than that logo, plus no yellow E underneath.

How can I do that sort of effect? Currently I do not have Illustrator.

I do however, have Photoshop, an older CS6 version, would it be better to create the logo in Photoshop and is there a way to do it in that program as an alternative?

I am using Adobe InDesign CC 2018 on Mac OS Sierra.

I would gladly appreciate any advice on doing this; tried doing some Google-ing on text effects, but aren't certain with this.

Comment: This is a typical Illustrator job.

Answer (score 3):

This **can't** be done with InDesign short of creating text outlines and then *manually* moving anchors, converting anchor points, and adjusting Bezier handles for each and every letter.

Will **Illustrator** it's fairly straight-forward.

- Set the text
- Select the text with the **Selection Tool** (not the Text tool).
- Choose **`Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp`**
- Then Choose **`Bulge`** for the warp options and move the slider until you are happy.
- Click **`OK`**
- Save
- Then use **`File > Place`** in InDeisgn to place the artwork there.

[image]

If you want to have it directly in Indesign *without* the dependency on the Illustrator file...

After Clicking `OK` in Illustrator for the warp options, merely choose **`Edit > Copy`** in **Illustrator**, *switch* to **Indesign** and chose **`Edit > Paste`**.

It will Paste into InDesign as a group of shapes:

[image]

Comment: In InDesign, [a script](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/464428) can move the points for you, but yeah, simply using the right tool is so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Not in InDesign, but you can easily do it in Photoshop (although I'd highly recommend to do that in Illustrator or another vector software).

1. make your text a Smart Object
2. use Transform (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and select "Switch between free transform and warp modes"
3. in the "Warp" dropdown, choose "Bulge" and insert a negative value for "Bend" (should be something around -10, adjust to fit your text)

From there you can either export as a PDF or insert the PSD directly into your InDesign project.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in InDesign.

You just need to first rotate your text to a desired angle to what you might be working.
For example say isometric view, so you align
the text to the edges, keeping in mind the verticals will remain straight to like the alphabets (because of which we are doing this, we need the text in a distorted perspective or any other view, but not 90degrees to the Alphabet itself.)

After rotating, go to Type -> Create Outlines
Then with the Selection Tool, you can resize it, and it will distort in your desired angle. More or less it's a makeshift solution. You have to adjust and see, but it did align for me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! I have a hard time imagining what you describe here and how it can look like the example image. Perhaps you could add a screenshot or gif showing your method?